# How do I find the .NET framework version used in an SSIS 2008 R2 package?

Tags: sql, ssis, version, .net

How do I find the .NET framework version used in an SSIS 2008 R2 package?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have probably found an answer to your question by now. This is for others who might stumble upon this question. Here is one possible way to find out the .NET version used by an SSIS package. Version can be found with the help of a `Script Task`. Following example shows how this can be done. This example uses `SSIS 2008 R2`.

**Step-by-step process:**

1. On the SSIS package's `Control Flow` tab, place a `Script Task` as shown in screenshot #**1**.
2. Double-click on the `Script Task` to bring up the **Script Task Editor** as shown in screenshot #**2**. You can also right-click on the `Script Task` and select `Edit...` option to bring up the `Script Task Editor`.
3. On the `Script Task Editor`, click the **Edit Script...** button. This will open a new IDE with the `Script Task` code as shown in screenshot #**3**.
4. On the `Script Task code IDE`, click on the menu `View` --> `Project Explorer` to open the project explorer as shown in screenshot #**4**.
5. On the `Project Explorer`, double-click on the `Properties` to open the properties pane as shown in the screenshot #**5**.
6. **Target Framework** field on the `Application` section of the `Properties` pane shown in the screenshot #**6** should display the .NET framework version.

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]