# ReSharper 8.1 hanging dialog when editing SSIS package script tasks in VS.NET 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, resharper

I've just upgraded from **ReSharper 7** to **ReSharper 8.1** and am working on an **SSIS package** solution in **Visual Studio 2012**, with the required add-ons installed to enable the Business Intelligence templates and project types.

Everytime I open up a Script task within the SSIS package, which launches a new VSTA IDE, I get a small, semi-opaque ReSharper dialog that says either `"Saving Caches"` or `"Merging assemblies"` (I'm not sure what causes the variance) - the dialog has a small progress bar which *never* moves, and the dialog only goes away if I suspend/re-enable ReSharper from Tools -> Options in VS2012.

Other solution types are fine (MVC applications, Class libraries and so on).

Does anybody know if there's a setting that I can change to stop this from occurring?

It's a bit of a nuisance as it's always on top and in the centre of the screen.

This did not occur previously with ReSharper 7 enabled when working with these projects.

Comment: I recommend you post this issue at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com for someone to take a look at. If you can attach your solution that would be great, too.

Comment: This is most probably due to a .net framework mismatch. SQL Server 2012 (and thus SSIS) only supports up to 4.0, while ReSharper 8.1 runs on 4.6.1+. If your SQL Server is 2014+, then you should be able to just change the target framework version in the script task. You can find instructions in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692944/how-do-i-find-the-net-framework-version-used-in-an-ssis-2008-r2-package