# SSIS 2012 package running OK in win 10 but not in win 7/win server 2012

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a SSIS package downloading a file from an URL.
https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/market/sec_tradinfo/stampfx/2020/Documents/20200831.xls

in win10 machine, such package is running ok. here is the code that's related to the download.

[image]

However, in win 7 the same package keeps giving "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" exception.

[image]

Both win7 and win10 machines are updated to .net framework 4.8 and I double checked the properties of the SSIS script task are targeted to the latest .net framework version allowed in VS2012 SSIS IDE.

I double checked the internet proxy as well. I can access the URL from chrome and can download the file without any issue.

What am I missing? Please help me with what is the big difference between win 7 and win 10 for SSIS package.

Thanks.

Edit: add "SSIS target" according to comment
[image]

Comment: It's not about which framework is installed on the computer. [What version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6240518/11683) does your SSIS target?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#if-your-app-targets-a-net-framework-version-earlier-than-47?

Comment: tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#schusestrongcrypto and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn786418(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN but no luck