# Is SSIS 2008 compatible with .Net framework 3.5

Tags: windows-7, .net-3.5, ssis, .net-2.0

I have developed SSIS packages on a machine where .Net framework 3.5, Windows Xp are installed. But when i deploy those in machine where OS is Windows 7.0 and .Net framework 2.0 is there, packages without script component are running well. but packages with script components are trowing error as access to a file path is denied. When i try to debug the package on deployment machine i found that the exception comes from script component.

I want to know is there any relationship between SSIS 2008 and .Net framework in case of script component?

Comment: I have created 2008 packages with script tasks that used the 3.5 framework just fine. Are you referencing a custom DLL that isn't in the GAC? Can you post your code and the exact error message?

Comment: Please post the full error. How can we tell which path is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065673/reference-a-net-3-5-assembly-in-a-script-task-in-ssis-2005)

basically with SSIS 2005 you are stuck with .net 2.0 (and VB)

On SSIS 2008, .net 2.0 is the dafault, but you can set it to use 3.5. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692944/how-do-i-find-the-net-framework-version-used-in-an-ssis-2008-r2-package) you have print screens on how to do it